# Error with SQL Server connection: Win32Exception: The parameter is incorrect

Tags: .net-core, database-connection, sql-server-2014, connection-string

I sent an app for production but I'm getting what appears to be a connection error.

And this is the error when I invoke the api URL

> Win32Exception: The parameter is incorrect.
> Unknown location
>
> SqlException: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 25 - Connection string is not valid)

The error itself is pretty self-explanatory but as far as I understand the connection string is OK

Here's the `appsettings.json` in C#:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "Hawk": "Data Source=Hawk.db",
    "HawkSQLServer": "Server=vgcserver2\\MSSQLSERVER;Database=HawkNew;User Id=sa;Password=password;"
  }
}
```

The database is named `HawkNew` and user `sa` has the same password from the connection string (SQL Server 2014).

The server's `web.config` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
        <system.webServer>
            <handlers>
                <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" 
                     modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
            </handlers>
            <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\BackEnd.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="true" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess" />
        </system.webServer>
    </location>
</configuration>
```

Comment: If this is the first time your app is being installed in production, I suggest you get a network engineer involved and make sure traffic is permitted between your webserver and your database (there are usually firewalls stopping everything).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot Connect to Server - A network-related or instance-specific error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18060667/cannot-connect-to-server-a-network-related-or-instance-specific-error)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure - but `MSSQLSERVER` is typically the "internal" name of the default, unnamed instance - which you **do not** have to specify when connecting to that server instance.

So I'd try these settings in `appsettings.json`:

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "Hawk": "Data Source=Hawk.db",
    "HawkSQLServer": "Server=vgcserver2;Database=HawkNew;User Id=sa;Password=password;"
}
```

Also, word of caution: it's generally considered a **really bad practice** to use the `sa` account for your development and especially for production use. Use Windows authentication, if possible - or else create a specific user for your application that has the needed permissions - do **NOT** use the system administrator account for any serious work!

Comment: Thank you, the 'sa' thing is just for an in-house development, this is the earliest stage but it had to be in production mode for the client to get convinced.